# Convergence in probability of order statistic random variables with uniform distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, random-variables

Please verify if my solution to this exercise has any mistake (Specially in the second part):

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of iid random variables with distribuction uniform $U[0,1]$. Show that $X_{(n)} \to 1$ in probability.

Let $0<\epsilon\leq1$.
Then $$P(|X_{(n)} - 1|> \epsilon) = P(|1 - X_{(n)}| > \epsilon) = P(1 - X_{(n)} > \epsilon) = P(X_{(n)} < 1 - \epsilon) = F_{X_{(n)}}(1-\epsilon) = {(F_{X_n}(1-\epsilon))}^n = (1-\epsilon)^n \to 0$$

If $\epsilon>1$, then $P(|X_{(n)}-1|>\epsilon)=0$, since $X_{n}$ is never greater than $1$ nor less than $0$, then neither is $X_{(n)}$, so the distance from $X_{(n)}$ to $1$ can't be greater than $1$.

Thanks.

Comment: The extra thing with $\epsilon>1$ is not necessary, you can always change $\forall \epsilon>0$ to $\forall \epsilon \in (0,a]$ with $a>0$ fixed. But in general the proof is correct.

Comment: what is $a$ and could you explain why this substitution is possible?

Comment: $a$ can be any positive constant you like. In general this will work because you are trying to prove something of the form $(\forall \epsilon>0) P(\epsilon)$ where the predicate $P(\epsilon)$ is by its structure "monotone", i.e. $P(\epsilon_1) \Rightarrow P(\epsilon_2)$ if $\epsilon_1<\epsilon_2$. For example, for $X_n \to X$ in probability, $\{ |X_n-X|>\epsilon_1 \} \supset \{ |X_n-X|>\epsilon_2 \}$ so $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon_1) \geq P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon_2)$. Thus to deal with $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+$ it is sufficient to deal with $\epsilon \in (0,a]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is definitely right.

Actually we only care the case when $\epsilon$ is very small rather than large $\epsilon$, because you want to prove when $n \rightarrow \infty$, there is no difference between $X_{(n)}$ and $1$ in almost every point of domain (except the subset of domain whose measure is 0), so you will try to use smaller $\epsilon$ as possible.