# Fraction of the largest element of a sum of N i.i.d. random variates sampled from some distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, order-statistics, extreme-value-analysis

I want to figure out how the fraction of the biggest sample of the sum of some iid samples from an arbitrary distribution varies.

For example, I have a random variable $X \sim f(x)$, and I sampled $n$ iid samples, denoted as $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\}$. Clearly when $n=1$, the fraction $\left(\max\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n \right) / \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)$ is simply $1$. When the variance is infinite, as $n$ grows, the fraction may reach $1$. However, if the variance is finite, it should slowly go to $\frac{1}{n}$.

It is a hunch that how the fraction converges to where is related to some properties of $f(x)$. Is there any way that I can describe this fraction as some function of $f$ and $n$, maybe an upper/lower bound?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that $X$ is almost surely bounded, then we can give a pretty straightforward answer :

Let, $X, x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be i.i.d. and denote by $x_{(n)}:=\max\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ the maximum [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic), and assume that $\|X\|_\infty = M$ for some $M>0$, where $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ denotes the [essential supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_infimum_and_essential_supremum).

Then [it can be shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809183/convergence-in-probability-of-order-statistic-random-variables-with-uniform-dist) that $x_{(n)}\to M$ in probability (in fact almost surely, by Borel-Cantelli).

On the other hand, the law of large numbers yields $\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \to \mathbb E[X] $ in probability as well.

Therefore, provided that $\mathbb E[X]\ne 0$, continuous mapping theorem yields
$$n\cdot \frac{x_{(n)}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} = \frac{x_{(n)}}{\frac 1 n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} \to \frac{M}{\mathbb E[X]} $$
in probability (or almost surely...) as $n\to\infty$. Hence for large $n$, the ratio $\frac{x_{(n)}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$ behaves like $\mathcal O(1/n)$, as you observed in your simulations.

---

The case unbounded $X$ or infinite variance is much more delicate to handle.

One thing you can do is note that the CDF of $x_{n}$ is given by $\mathbb P(x_{(n)}\le t) = F_X(t)^n $ where $F_X$ is the CDF of $X$. Hence if the sequence $F_X^n$ converges pointwise to some limit CDF $F$, then you can apply [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) to find a limiting distribution of $\frac{x_{(n)}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am also curious about a variant of this problem. Since the ratio $x_{(n)} / \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ can be considered as $\|\mathbf{p}_x - \mathbf{u}\|_{\infty}$, where $p_x$ is a vector whose elements are $x_i / \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and $\mathbf{u}$ is uniform distribution, and we know that $\|\cdot\|_{\infty} \geq \|\cdot\|_2$, can we have a looser condition than almost surely converge for the first conclusion if the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ (the fraction) is replaced with $\|\cdot\|_2$? I am also interested in ways we can play around with the infinite variation case with the $L_2$ norm.

Comment: you're welcome. Sorry I don't understand your other question, how is the ratio equal to  $\|\mathbf{p}_x - \mathbf{u}\|_{\infty}$ ? What would be the distribution of $\mathbf u$ exactly ? maybe make another separate question to clarify ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I did make some mistakes and they are not equal. I will reexamine my formulations and open another question. Thank you very much.